# Keep command history between (i)python sessions

Tags: python, shell, command-line

When I open a python or ipython from command-line, I don't have commands history from previous use, using up key
Is there a way to configure it, to remember commands, like a .bash_history?

Comment: If I type '1+1', then close 'Ctrl+z', then reopen and press up-arrow, nothing is shown

Comment: just seen it works by exiting with exit()...

Comment: also note that ipython is actually different to the python interactive shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exit ipython cleanly with <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd> and ipython should do this by default.